# Evaluation Board DP83TD510E

Tags: microcontroller, usb, ethernet, texas-instruments

I'm trying to create a demo based on 2 evaluation boards **DP83TD510E-EVM** using 10Base-T1L technology. Both boards are connected together via a 10 meter SPE cable and each board is connected to a laptop via Ethernet cable. Both Boards are also powered through USB (No external power supply).
The idea is to try to send a packet from laptop A to B.
But I am strugling to understand how the boards are supposed to work.
What i managed until now is to install the drivers for windows, use **USB-2-MDIO** to open Board's port. I also read 0 in each register so i don't know if that's even a problem.

So could anyone tell me what are the right steps to do in order to send a packet?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you asked TI?

Comment: I cannot, since i need to own a company email

Comment: I don’t seem to have an issue contacting TI with my personal email. There’s also you local distributor or FAE.